# Find all $n$ such that $\gcd(3n-4, n^2+1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

> I need to find all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $3n-4$ and $n^2+1$ would be coprime numbers.

I was thinking about using Euclidean algorithm - if two numbers $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then exist integers $c$ and $d$: $ac+bd=1$. So if there do not exist integers $c$ and $d$, then my numbers won’t be coprime.

Another idea is checking some $n$, what I saw is that when $n=3$ or $-2$, the common factor is $5$. Maybe it is always related to number $5$?

And the last thing, always one number is even and another is odd. So their common factor is either $1$, or bigger than $2$.

Any better ideas? :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Euclidean algorithm is a good starting point. In particular recall [these properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid's_algorithm) of the $\gcd$.

Hint. Since $3n-4$ is not divisible by $3$, we may consider
$$\begin{align}\gcd(3n-4, n^2+1)&=\gcd(3n-4, 3n^2+3)\\&=\gcd(3n-4, (3n-4)(n+1)+n+7)\\&=\gcd(3n-4,n+7)\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. At end you will see that your remark about the common divisor $5$ is "almost" correct: the $\gcd$ can be $1$, $5$ or $25$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it! :)) 

Comment: @IEVAŠAPOVALOVAITĖ Well done! Since you are new here why don't you take a few seconds for a tour? https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

The extended Euclidean algorithm performed in $\mathbb Q[n]$ [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialextendedGCD%5B3+n+-+4,+n%5E2+%2B+1%5D)
$$
25 = -(3n+4)(3n-4)+9(n^2+1)
$$
Therefore, $\gcd(3n-4, n^2+1)$ divides $25$.